# Grails 3 - Tomcat Url mapping

Tags: tomcat, grails

I'm working with:

- JDK 1.8.0
- JRE 1.8.0
- Grails 3.3.0
- Groovy 2.4.12
- Tomcat 8.5
- IntellijIdea 2017

I create an empty app and It works with run-app, also I deploy it with artifacts from intellij
in exploded mode and it works in Tomcat too.
But if change in the controller urlmapping:

/"(view:"/index") for -> "/"(controller: 'initio', action: 'index')

there is the controller and the view.

it woks fine only with run-app, when I deploy it in Tomcat I get an error:

**Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error
Tipo Informe de Excepción
mensaje Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.
excepción
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1266)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:166)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:108)
nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de diario del servidor.**

I don't know what's wrong !
Thanks in advance. Regards

Comment: Do you have `error.gsp` inside grails-app/views?

Comment: Are you starting tomcat from the project directory?

Comment: there is the grails-app/views/error.gsp. it works fine with the embedded tomcat in Intellij and when i deploy it in the Tomcat server, different from intellij, as long as i don't change the urlmapping controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think a got it. it's an issue with the IDE(Intellij IDEA 2017). I create an app just with grails' commands and it works fine, then i modify urlmapping controller and works fine too (both embedded and service Tomcat - Server). Then a load it in Intellij, deploy it and it works !